# Move the first three items in row [0] to new columns in rows[1 - 9]

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I want to cut the first line in row [0], delete it and move into three new columns, in rows 1 -9

I cannot find any details to cut and move row 0 to rows 1 - 10, then delete row 0.
I have searched StackOverflow and cannot find any similar questions/answers.

I would appreciate any assistance.

Regards,

Clive

change from:
     0         1     2       3      4       5        6     7       8      9       10       11

0 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '148']
1 ['3020', '2820', '3040', '2880', '1740', '1360', '980', '990', '1410', '1770', '2580', '2630']
2 ['3020', '2820', '3040', '2880', '1740', '1360', '980', '990', '1410', '1770', '2580', '2630']
3 ['3020', '2820', '3040', '2880', '1740', '1360', '980', '990', '1410', '1770', '2580', '2630']
4 ['3020', '2820', '3040', '2880', '1740', '1360', '980', '990', '1410', '1770', '2580', '2630']
5 ['3020', '2820', '3040', '2880', '1740', '1360', '980', '990', '1410', '1770', '2580', '2630']
6 ['3020', '2820', '3040', '2880', '1740', '1360', '980', '990', '1410', '1770', '2580', '2630']
7 ['3020', '2820', '3040', '2880', '1740', '1360', '980', '990', '1410', '1770', '2580', '2630']
8 ['3020', '2820', '3040', '2880', '1740', '1360', '980', '990', '1410', '1770', '2580', '2630']
9 ['3020', '2820', '3040', '2880', '1740', '1360', '980', '990', '1410', '1770', '2580', '2630']
10 ['3020', '2820', '3040', '2880', '1740', '1360', '980', '990', '1410', '1770', '2580', '2630']
0 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '311']
1 ['490', '290', '280', '230', '200', '250', '440', '530', '460', '420', '530', '450']
2 ['490', '290', '280', '230', '200', '250', '440', '530', '460', '420', '530', '450']
3 ['490', '290', '280', '230', '200', '250', '440', '530', '460', '420', '530', '450']
4 ['490', '290', '280', '230', '200', '250', '440', '530', '460', '420', '530', '450']
5 ['490', '290', '280', '230', '200', '250', '440', '530', '460', '420', '530', '450']
6 ['490', '290', '280', '230', '200', '250', '440', '530', '460', '420', '530', '450']
7 ['490', '290', '280', '230', '200', '250', '440', '530', '460', '420', '530', '450']
8 ['490', '290', '280', '230', '200', '250', '440', '530', '460', '420', '530', '450']
9 ['490', '290', '280', '230', '200', '250', '440', '530', '460', '420', '530', '450']
10 ['490', '290', '280', '230', '200', '250', '440', '530', '460', '420', '530', '450']

[image: Grid-1]

to:
     0           1     2      3       4       5       6      7        8       9     10    11       12      13      14

0 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '148', '3020', '2820', '3040', '2880', '1740', '1360', '980', '990', '1410', '1770', '2580', '2630']
1 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '148', '3020', '2820', '3040', '2880', '1740', '1360', '980', '990', '1410', '1770', '2580', '2630']
2 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '148', '3020', '2820', '3040', '2880', '1740', '1360', '980', '990', '1410', '1770', '2580', '2630']
3 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '148', '3020', '2820', '3040', '2880', '1740', '1360', '980', '990', '1410', '1770', '2580', '2630']
4 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '148', '3020', '2820', '3040', '2880', '1740', '1360', '980', '990', '1410', '1770', '2580', '2630']
5 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '148', '3020', '2820', '3040', '2880', '1740', '1360', '980', '990', '1410', '1770', '2580', '2630']
6 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '148', '3020', '2820', '3040', '2880', '1740', '1360', '980', '990', '1410', '1770', '2580', '2630']
7 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '148', '3020', '2820', '3040', '2880', '1740', '1360', '980', '990', '1410', '1770', '2580', '2630']
8 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '148', '3020', '2820', '3040', '2880', '1740', '1360', '980', '990', '1410', '1770', '2580', '2630']
9 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '148', '3020', '2820', '3040', '2880', '1740', '1360', '980', '990', '1410', '1770', '2580', '2630']
0 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '311','490', '290', '280', '230', '200', '250', '440', '530', '460', '420', '530', '450']
1 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '311','490', '290', '280', '230', '200', '250', '440', '530', '460', '420', '530', '450']
2 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '311','490', '290', '280', '230', '200', '250', '440', '530', '460', '420', '530', '450']
3 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '311','490', '290', '280', '230', '200', '250', '440', '530', '460', '420', '530', '450']
4 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '311','490', '290', '280', '230', '200', '250', '440', '530', '460', '420', '530', '450']
5 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '311','490', '290', '280', '230', '200', '250', '440', '530', '460', '420', '530', '450']
6 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '311','490', '290', '280', '230', '200', '250', '440', '530', '460', '420', '530', '450']
7 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '311','490', '290', '280', '230', '200', '250', '440', '530', '460', '420', '530', '450']
8 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '311','490', '290', '280', '230', '200', '250', '440', '530', '460', '420', '530', '450']
9 ['Grid-ref=', '1', '311','490', '290', '280', '230', '200', '250', '440', '530', '460', '420', '530', '450']

[image: Grid-2]

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV format seems a bit off.

```py
import csv

# open both files
with open("myfile.csv", "r") as f1:
    with open("destination.csv", "w") as f2:
        # create a CSV reader and writer for them
        read = csv.reader(f1)
        writ = csv.writer(f2)

        # start your counter
        counter = 0
        for r in read: # iterate through the first file
            if counter == 0: #if 0 mod 11, it's your reference
                ref = r
            else: # else, you concatenate your reference with the row
                writ.writerow(ref + r)
            # adapt the counter, modulo 11 (will do ...7,8,9,10,0,1,2,3,...)
            counter = (counter+1)%11
```

This will read the document, and every 11 rows (determined by the `%10`), it will consider the current row as a "reference". For the next 10 rows, it will append this reference to the beginning of the row. Everything is read from the first file, and written to the second.

Your content, as-is, doesn't seem to be a valid CSV (with the line numbers and the square brackets). I guess the numbers come from a bad copy-paste. About the square brackets, if they indeed are part of your data, you should clean that, either in your data or in this script.